# Trim String After Keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column that contains status changes, but I don't want to return the whole string.  Is there any way to return just a part of a string after a certain keyword?  Every value of the column is in the format of From X to Y where X and Y could be a single word or multiple words.  I've looked at the `substring` and `trim` functions, but those seem to require knowledge of how many spaces you want to keep.

Edit:  I want to keep part Y from the status and get rid of 'From X to'.

Comment: What database are you using?  What are examples of some of the values and what you want?

Comment: It's a DB on SQL Server 2012.
A status could look like "From Authorized to Auth Not Needed"

Comment: if 1. the keyword doesn't come more then 3 times and 2. you have no `.` in your string then try a trick : `declare @field varchar(200) = 'From X to Y'
declare @keyword varchar(200) = 'to '
select parsename(REPLACE(@field,@keyword,'.'),1) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of Charindex and Substring and Len to do it.

Try this:

```
select SUBSTRING(field,charindex('keyword',field), LEN('keyword'))
```

So this will find Flop and extract it wherever it is in the field

```
select SUBSTRING('bullflop',charindex('flop','bullflop'), LEN('flop'))
```

EDIT:

To get the remainder then just set LEN to the field `LEN(field)`

```
declare @field varchar(200)
set @field = 'this is bullflop and other such junk'
select SUBSTRING(@field,charindex('flop',@field), LEN(@field) )
```

EDIT 2:

Now I understand, here is  a quick and dirty version...

```
declare @field varchar(200)
set @field = 'From X to Y'
select Replace(SUBSTRING(@field,charindex('to ',@field), LEN(@field) ), 'to ','')
```

Returns:

`Y`

EDIT 3:

Cory is right, this is cleaner.

```
declare @field varchar(200) = 'From X to Y'
declare @keyword varchar(200) = 'to '
select SUBSTRING(@field,charindex(@keyword,@field) + LEN(@keyword), LEN(@field) )
```

Comment: "part of a string after a certain keyword". I don't think they want to extract a keyword, but find the remainder of the string *after* said keyword.

Comment: Cory is correct.  I want the Y part of the string after the word 'to'.

Comment: You could have a separate variable for the keyword 'to ' and instead of the replacement, add its length onto the result of the charindex function. Maybe slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are fine, but I like the `STUFF()` function and it doesn't seem to be well-known, so here's another option:

```
DECLARE @field VARCHAR(50) = 'From Authorized to Auth Not Needed'
       ,@keyword VARCHAR(50) = ' to '
SELECT STUFF(@field,1,CHARINDEX(@keyword,@field)+LEN(@keyword),'')
```

`STUFF()` is like `SUBSTRING()` and `REPLACE()` combined, you feed it a string, a start position and a length, and can replace that with anything or in your case, nothing `''`.

From MSDN:

```
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )
```

Comment: Never knew that `STUFF()` existed. Interesting!

Comment: Not sure this would work since the length of the statuses could vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a few string functions to do what you want:

```
DECLARE @Field varchar(100) = 'From A to Z'
DECLARE @Keyword varchar(100) = 'to'

-- Method 1 (Find the keyword, then take the remainder of the string)
SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Field, 
    CHARINDEX(@Keyword, @Field, 0) + LEN(@Keyword), LEN(@Field)))
```

**EDIT**:

```
-- Method 2 (Take from the right the characters up to the keyword)
SELECT RIGHT(@Field, LEN(@Field) - CHARINDEX(@Keyword, @Field, 0) - LEN(@Keyword))
```

Produces:

```
'Z'
```